# JSP page cannot be compiled ? why?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, openid

```
Problem accessing /consumer_redirect.jsp. Reason:

PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP

OpenIDException cannot be resolved to a type

at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:107)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:280)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:350)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:411)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:470)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:364)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Can you post some code instead of just the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is given right there in the error:

> `OpenIDException cannot be resolved to a type`

It is unable to resolve the symbol `OpenIDException` in your code. Make sure you have all of your `import` statements, check your classpath, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `OpenIDException` in your JSP code.

```
<%@ page import="org.openid4java.OpenIDException" %>
```